# Getting workitem informaton through query

Tags: tfs

I have a scenario in which I want to show the following columns defined in the query but when I bind the workitems collection to the grid it is getting some columns defined in the query and some are missing, also I am seeing some extra columns which i have not define in the query.

```
const string wiqlQuery = @"SELECT [System.Id], 
                                  [System.Title], 
                                  [System.AssignedTo],
                                  [Microsoft.VSTS.Scheduling.CompletedWork], 
                                  [Microsoft.VSTS.Scheduling.RemainingWork] 
                           FROM WorkItems 
                           WHERE  [System.WorkItemType] = 'Document' 
                              and [Tyler.Document.Type] = '03-Design Document' 
                           ORDER BY [System.Title]";

var workItems = workItemStore1.Query(wiqlQuery);
dataGridView1.DataSource = workItems;
```

Comment: I'm not sure what the question is here. And does the query work properly if you run it in team explorer?

Comment: yes the query works fine from team explorer. the question is it is not showing all the fields in the grid.

Comment: Which is it, TFS 2008, or TFS 2010.  It can't be both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the fields are custom fields, you are going to have to get them explicitly and bind them explicitly.  Only the standard "system" fields are exposed as properties.  The rest you have to get through an array.

Answer (score 0):

When your grid has 'autofinding' columns, it could be possible that the returned result shows only the fields that have data.

Comment: Thats not the case , those field have data.